# Swapping G8 Halogen Under-cabinet fixtures for LED

Tags: lighting, led

I've got 6 under-cabinet fixtures that use G8 20V bulbs. I'd like to swap them for LEDs. I've tried putting in bulbs but there's some difference in the voltage load and there's a lot of flickering. So my next step I guess is to swap the fixtures. They're direct wired around the perimeter of the kitchen, controlled by a switch. Should I expect this to be somewhat straight forward (is anything? :-) )? Should I expect there to be more to swapping one for the other than connecting the new one up to where the old one was, moving the old fixture wire connection to the new fixture wire connection? I haven't opened one up yet but I assumed the fixture is connected to the wires in the wall via some wire nut or similar.

Comment: Some of those supplies give a 20V AC output not DC which may cause the flickering...

Comment: It's quite likely the voltage is AC.  You will need LED bulbs that play nicely with AC; that's not hugely complicated but it does add a nickel to the manufacturing cost. So J random cheapie/dollar store/Amazon Marketplace/ebay bulbs may not have that feature.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica probably easier to fit a rectifier...

Answer (score 1):

Are you correct in the questions?  Should it be G8 20 watts not 20V.
To replace the G8 20 Watt/120v build it is a direct straight replacement.  Since you did do the swap, but it is flicking, there could be two issues

1. The replacement LEDs were not dimmerable and you have a dinner in the switch
2. The replacements are dimmerable, but the dimmer is not rated for LED bulbs.